# Joomla configuration for livesite and admin

Tags: .htaccess, joomla, configuration

I installed Joomla in peterrisman.com/PilotMarketingStrategy-J/

I successfully built a new website

So far, so good.

I pointed pilotmarketingstrategy.com to peterrisman.com/PilotMarketingStrategy-J/

I updated .htaccess with RewriteBase /

I updated configuration.php with public $live_site = 'http:// pilotmarketingstrategy.com'

Viola! the site is live... **BUT**

I can't log into the admin from pilotmarketingstrategy.com/admin/index.php - it doesn't recognize my ID or p/w.

In order for me to log into the admin, I have to change configuration.php back to public $live_site = 'http:// peterrisman.com/PilotMarketingStrategy-J/'. When I'm finished, I have to change back to public $live_site = 'http:// pilotmarketingstrategy.com'

This **CAN'T** be right. Does anyone know how to properly configure Joomla so that both the live site and admin share the same domain?

Comment: @Neil Robertson i was hopeful, but no luck. 
i changed the $live_site = ''; pilotmarketingstrategy.com works fine. 
but my id/pw are not recognized when i try to sign in to pilotmarketingstrategy.com/administrator/index.php 
any other suggestions??

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `live_site` parameter to null so the line in your `configuration.php` file should look like this:

```
public $live_site = '';
```

Recent Joomla installs rarely need this parameter to be set.

Comment: i was hopeful, but no luck.

i changed the $live_site = '';

pilotmarketingstrategy.com works fine.

but my id/pw are not recognized when i try to sign in to pilotmarketingstrategy.com/administrator/index.php

any other suggestions??

Answer (score 0):

A lot of comments on the "live_site" configuration element make vague claims about it not being required.

In fact, it is essential for correct operation of Joomla in a PHP-FPM environment. Joomla does not detect the site information properly in this environment.